# Table html with colspan to DIV & CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

Searched myself crazy but cannot seem to find a solution to properly display a table in divs, with CSS. 
As you can see I would like the head cells to have a colspan="2". How to manage the below code with just divs and CSS?

Edit; tried `display: table-caption` and nested tables but didnt get the desired result.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Facilities</td>
    <td colspan="2">Companies</td>
    <td colspan="2">Info</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Facility 1</td>
    <td>yes</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Company x</td>
    <td>Info?</td>
    <td>yes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not just leave it as a table?

Comment: What are you wanting it to look like..?

Comment: As i tend to believe that combining divs and css is the proper way to code nowadays?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you tried settings the `divs`? Also, @ElGavilan I agree. If its tabular data, use a `table` - its exactly _made for that purpose_. You shouldn't use tables for layout, but sure as hell use them for tabular data...

Comment: Want it to look like the html that is provided.. so 3 headings with colspan 2 and a row below with 2 cells per heading.

Comment: @RobbertT There is nothing wrong with using tables for tabular data. Using tables for layout is what you're hearing about.

Comment: @RobbertT So in other words, you need to use a `<table>`...

Comment: Ok cool, i was just wondering how to do this in divs and css.. Thanks. Any suggestions are welcome though

Comment: You need to ask a specific question for one specific problem. Asking for suggestions or tutorials will get this closed.

Comment: `<div>`s are generally used for page layout. You have tabular data, which is what `<table>`s were made for. Recreating your HTML with divs would be much more work than it would be worth when what you currently have works perfectly fine.

Comment: Actually, you can't. This is a limitation of CSS `display: table-cell`. You may try `flex` and `grid`, but then you need to think what you are wanting to achieve and why. Better stick to `table` if your requirement is to simply present tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As i tend to believe that combining `divs` and CSS is the proper way to code [tables] nowadays?

Tabular data should be represented in a table. That is what the `table` element is for. The data you've provided in your question *is* tabular data, so the `table` element is perfect for this.

The table display given in CSS is a way of allowing people to use tables for display *without* abusing the `table` element for non-tabular data (as had been done heavily in the past before this was introduced). A limitation of this however, [as Abhitalks commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966736/table-html-with-colspan-to-div-css/31967228#comment51841224_31966736), is that the CSS version allow us to recreate `rowspan`.

There's no need to reinvent the wheel when it doesn't need reinventing.

Comment: What about resizing? I'd like the table columns to become rows after a certain screen width.

Comment: display:table-row  would do;)

Comment: @RobbertT I meant `rowspan`, not `colspan`. Regardless, you can't properly implement `colspan` and your data is tabular and thus belongs in a `table`.